# How to use facebook appid to work with multiple domains (not sub domains)

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, multiple-domains

I have created an app on facebook and i am using that appid in my application to allow the users to login, like & share the content.

While creating the facebook app i have given a domain like "abc.com" in the "App Domains".

This is working fine when i access the page from "abc.com/mypage" but i want to do the same from "xyz.com/mypage", "xxx.com/mypage" etc....

The facebook login is working for only "abc.com" it is not working for otherdomains.

How can i make this work and i want the same behavior for multiple domains more than 2

Thanks,

Comment: I have noticed that unbounce allows people to use social widgets facebook share/like buttons) on custom domain landing pages. Was curious how that works (as I haven't seen Unbounce asking its customers to create separate Facebook App IDs)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one domain per "platform". Meaning, if you got 2 different Websites, you need to create 2 different Apps. But you can use the same App for a Website on one domain and a Page Tab or Canvas App on another domain (which is useful for testing on localhost, for example).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick replay,

actually the application is deployed on same domain but in our app we are providing the landing pages so the user can customize the link of that page with there own link (domain)

Comment: The users would have to create their own App in that case, if they want to use their own domain.

Comment: I have noticed that unbounce allows people to use social widgets facebook share/like buttons) on custom domain landing pages. Was curious how that works (as I haven't seen Unbounce asking its customers to create separate Facebook App IDs) –

Comment: yeah, that´s what i mean. customers would have to create their own apps, with their own app IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to have multiple applications.
Look closer at the Settings-Basic, you would find that the domain setting is at the top and is global. Try to add a second domain and you see this error message: "This must be derived from Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL".

And that's the solution: You can make your secure canvas url `abc.com`, mobile url `xyz.com` and siteUrl `example.com`.

I guess your abc.com is for "Website". So what you need to do is click "Add Platform - Facebook Canvas". And enter `xyz.com/` as canvas url and `example.com/` as mobile url. Then you can have three domain supporting signing in at the same time.
Facebook acknowledges that people have the need to use different domains for different purposes. But they decided to allow only one domain per purpose. The error message suggests that you may have up to five different url and hence five domains.